# Unable to uninstall NVidia drivers completely (initramfs will attempt to resume from...)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, initramfs

I was trying to install nvidia drivers for my PC for so that xorg will use intel drivers. I followed this guide and did an installation a runfile using the command:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-396.24.run --no-opengl-files --dkms --no-drm
```

https://forums.fast.ai/t/successful-ubuntu-18-04-with-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda-work-setup/20128

The method didn't work for me. And now I'm trying to uninstall nvidia's drivers with `sudo apt purge nvidia*`

Somehow after doing this, now whenever I try to install/uninstall something I get a message like this:

```
....
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p3
I: (UUID=1e612fb7-d1f4-4a4a-a5bd-1ae6761c9bf0)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

And I can't even get the original nvidia driver to work. Any idea what the RESUME variable is? What is it that needs to be removed?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You can't purge with apt that was not installed with apt. Run `sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-396.24.run --uninstall` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work.... It says no nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: That was initially a bad idea to install drivers from a run file. And now after you partially removed it using apt it's a real problem. I don't know an obvious way how to clean this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>**Reinstall the nouveau-firmware...**</strike>

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall nouveau-firmware`

There are two **resume** parameters that I know of, and two that would effect the **initramfs**.

**Kernel parameter:**

1. In `terminal`... (permanent)...

   - `sudo blkid` # get a list of partitions and UUID's
   - `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file
   - find "quiet splash" and change it to something like "quiet splash resume=/dev/nvme0n1p3"
   - *note: nvme0n1p3 should be your swap partition*
   - `sudo update-grub` # update the grub files
   - `reboot` # reboot the computer
2. via the `GRUB` menu... (temporary)...

   - hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
   - find "quiet splash"
   - change it to "quiet splash resume=/dev/nvme0n1p3
   - *note: nvme0n1p3 should be your swap partition*
   - <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> to continue booting...

**initramfs:**

3. In `terminal`...

   - `sudo blkid` # get a list of partitions and UUID's
   - `sudo -H /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` # edit this file
   - `RESUME=UUID=1e612fb7-d1f4-4a4a-a5bd-1ae6761c9bf0` # edit with correct UUID
   - *note: UUID should be from swap partition*
   - `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` # update initrd.img
   - `reboot` # reboot the computer

Comment: is nouveau-firmware an alternative to nvidia? It doesn't seem to be available in Ubuntu 18.04's repo. I don't seem to have the file "/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume" either.

Comment: @matohak I removed the nouveau-firmware from my answer. With all of the resume things that I call out, you have to make sure that you've got the correct /dev/xxxx or UUID for the swap partition. `sudo blkid` will give you that information. Go ahead and create the missing file... it won't hurt.

Comment: #3 seems to have got rid of the error message for me.

Comment: @matohak glad it's working for you now!